# instalacao scapy sem precisar de interface grafica ou arquivo .exe

Tags: python, windows, script, .exe

Suadações amigos, Eu estou com um pequeno problema, eu estou criando um script python com scapy e npcap (que é requisito para o funcionamento do scapy) para rodar no windows. Entretanto, eu consegui fazer a instalação por meio de um executavel do scapy e de um executavel do npacp baixado diretamente do site oficial. Queria montar um script python para rodar no windows sem precisar abrir interface grafica de instalação do scapy e do npcap. Por exemplo, no Linux eu precisaria apenas copiar a biblioteca do scapy para a pasta, sem a necessidade de abrir uma interface grafica de instalação. Tem como eu instalar o scapy e o npcap em alguma pasta e apenas copiar os arquivos lá de dentro? Por exemplo, se eu quiser rodar o script em outro windows que ja tenha Python 2.7 instalado, apenas copiar os arquivos do scapy e do npcap?

Comment: Como está na resposta - a melhor forma de instalar pacotes de Python é pelo pip, na linha de comando - exatamente "sem interface gráfica ou .exe". No entanto, você não deveria basear seu projeto em Python 2 - e sim, usar Python 3.7 (é perfeitamenteepossível instalar os dois lado a lado no mesmo computador) - Python 2 está no fim do fim da vida, e é pouco provável que projetos de terceiros continuem sendo atualizados para funcionar com o mesmo.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode instalar o `scapy` utilizando o `pip` no `prompt` do Windows. Basta escrever

```
pip install scapy
```

Se houver alguma dependência necessária para o funcionamento do pacote, o `pip` se encarregará de instalá-lo para você.